# Inner Join ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Table structure for table Warehouse

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse (
  wID NUMBER(25)  ,
  Location VARCHAR2(70) ,
  Num_Employees NUMBER(25) ,
  Stock NUMBER(25) ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (wID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE WAREHOUSE_SEQ 
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    NOMAXVALUE;


INSERT INTO Warehouse (wID, Location, Num_Employees, Stock) 
    VALUES (WAREHOUSE_SEQ.nextval , 'Dallas', '3', '13');
INSERT INTO Warehouse (wID, Location, Num_Employees, Stock) 
    VALUES (WAREHOUSE_SEQ.nextval , 'Denver', '3', '07');
INSERT INTO Warehouse (wID, Location, Num_Employees, Stock) 
    VALUES (WAREHOUSE_SEQ.nextval , 'Detroit', '3', '09');
INSERT INTO Warehouse (wID, Location, Num_Employees, Stock) 
    VALUES (WAREHOUSE_SEQ.nextval , 'Phoenix', '3', '14');
INSERT INTO Warehouse (wID, Location, Num_Employees, Stock) 
    VALUES (WAREHOUSE_SEQ.nextval , 'Atlanta', '3', '07');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Orders.wID,
    person.name,
    Employee.*,
    Warehouse.wID
FROM person
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.wID = Warehouse.wID
    INNER JOIN Warehouse ON Warehouse.LOCATION=Employee.WORK_LOCATION
    INNER JOIN Employee ON Employees.ETYPE='Manager'
    WHERE Employee.EID = person.Id;
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You have only warehouse. where is person, orders, employee tables?

Comment: @realspirituals Sorry, but this comment doesn't make any sense. It should *never* be necessary to run catproc.sql on a live instance (see http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:765425826102).

Comment: Agreed and removed. Saw this as a solution from burleson if it persists. But i never faced or tried. Thats why i posted it as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.wID, person.name, Employee.*, Warehouse.wID 
FROM person INNER JOIN Employee         
ON   person.Id =  Employee.EID         
INNER JOIN Warehouse                        
ON Warehouse.LOCATION = Employee.WORK_LOCATION    
INNER JOIN Orders  
ON Orders.wID = Warehouse.wID
WHERE Employees.ETYPE ='Manager';
```

Comment: I don't see any reason - and neither for the downvotes of the other answers.

Comment: I suspect the downvote is there because this answer won't work. The error message is displayed because the first join is referencing an object (Warehouse) that hasn't been declared yet. Changing the join condition for the Employee table does not address the `ORA-00904`. The other answers are correct.

Comment: @StevieG In fact, this answer *will* work, because the ordering of the joins has been changed - Orders is now joined *after* Warehouse.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, it does work now. It was changed after my comment.

Comment: @StevieG Sorry, I had overlooked that the answer had been edited. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @StevieG1  1st I didn't fix the query but pointed out where the problem was which doesn't make it a wrong answer, down voting should only be used for wrong answers, criticism for the sake of criticisim isn't good enough pal

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your first join:
'FROM person INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.wID = Warehouse.wID'

The table 'Warehouse' is at this point not yet available, but you already mention it in the 'on' part.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.wID,
  person.NAME,
  Employee.*,
  Warehouse.wID
FROM person
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.EID = person.Id;
INNER JOIN Warehouse ON Warehouse.LOCATION = Employee.WORK_LOCATION
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.wID = Warehouse.wID
WHERE Employees.ETYPE = 'Manager'
```